# Get data from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get data from javascript function (someone created this function before, and I need to get the data from this function):

Here are the javascript function:

```
    function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
            document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k; 
document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
            document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
            document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
            document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
            setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
            document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
            document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
            document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
            document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
            document.getElementById('deptid').value=m;

    var params = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b);
          window.location.href="http://192.168.1.5/eleave/employee.php?lapplicant=" + params;

    }
```

**at PHP file I will use `b`.**

This is the button who calls `edit()`:

[image]

The code of that button are bellow:

```
<td align=\"center\">$uname</td><td align=\"center\">$loc1</td><td align=\"center\">$dept</td><td align=\"center\">$date</td><td align=\"center\"><button class=\"btn btn-mini\"data-toggle=\"modal\"href=\"#long\"
onClick=\"javascript:edit('$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist','newbal');\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\">
```

I've tried this javascript function in a new file:

```
function test_function() {
    var width = 8;
    var height = 9;

    window.location.href="http://localhost/belajar/get_test.php?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
}
```

and simply call in the PHP file such as:

```
<?php
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];

print($width . " " . $height);
?>
```

I want to get `b` in `edit()` and use it in PHP file. I've tried to use the 2nd part in edit function. But, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Seems there are 2 separate questions. The first part `edit()` does not relate to 2nd part.

Comment: Your test looks fine to me and should work. In edit() you do not do the window.location.href thing, so it does not transmit any data.

Comment: Does `test_function()` work (redirect to the page)? If not does it throw any errors? It should work from what you posted.

Comment: ya, it doesn't related. I just tried to get data from JS to PHP in 2nd part. And that's work. So, I tried at edit() hope it works, but doesn't work. I think because I use b which is from edit(b), Raptor

Comment: I've input  window.location.href in edit(), but because doesn't work so I just delete it. But, I've updated here I put again in the code above, colburton.

Comment: test_function() works, but when I tried to use window.location.href in edit() it doesn't work, Catalin. I thought it because I get b from edit(b){} but I don't know hot to do that. Do you have an idea?

Comment: `edit` won't work in the form you posted. It should show errors. You use `document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k7` where `k7` is an undeclared variable, and `document.getElementById('deptid').value=m m;` where `m m` can't even be a variable (and is also undeclared). Can you post all errors that come up in the console ?

Comment: There is no error appear when I run the page, Catalin. I thought that's typo, because someone had created this and I need to get b from edit(). Any idea?

Comment: 1, in edit(), you're trying to set value on the same document; 2, in test_function(), you're redirecting url with query passing. These two are different approaches. If you would like to have value set in current document using edit(), go for ajax. Btw, there's error in edit().

Comment: could you explain to have value set in current document using edit(), ydoow? thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and comments please? Do you just want to pass some variables from JS to PHP? If yes, how do you get this variables / where do you get them from ?

Comment: Yes, Catalin. I wanna get b from edit(), and use it in php file. I've updated my question. Thank you, hope you can help. :)

Comment: @LupitaNoyra you are passing the value of $uname to `b`. Try to alert b without setting anything and see what you have?